# "Canned version"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Someone bought a product and it was defective. The person contacted customer service and was given a 'canned version' of what he did not do right. What does "canned version" mean in this case? Thank you!

I apologize for Home Depot Canada not allowing people from other countries to view the link content. I really didn't know about it. I guess I deserve getting minus points for not knowing beforehand. Thank you.

Comment: Not spontaneous; prepared in advance; 'prepared in standardized form for nonspecific use or wide distribution' (Merriam-Webster Dictionary). Probably reading or copying from a script or set of standard responses.

Comment: What use is that (access denied) link to a Home Depot (Canada) page about a can of window or door insulating-foam sealant?

Comment: Unless there's a legitimate reason for that link, I have to assume it's some kind of search engine optimization trick (to promote sealant?) and the question should be deleted as spam.

Comment: I've just knocked the link out. It doesn't matter really whether it was added in error or supposed to be a link to the aforementioned product. Home Depot links are geofenced so are useless outside the US/CA.

Comment: Getting a ***canned*** response from Customer Services has overtones of the ***canned music*** that retailer might have playing in their stores. Effectively, it's ***general purpose, ready prepared*** (but not particularly important or relevant to any specific customer). It may also carry allusions to "condensed, squeezed together", as in ***canned sardines***. But I'd probably have used ***boilerplate*** myself, because that's probably closer to the intended sense.

Comment: canned here means the customer service person just "read a script".

Comment: Thank you for your explanations!

Comment: I actually think this question should remain open as the word canned is not used in its usual sense, for music, but is used to describe customer service script reading.

Comment: @Lambie I went to M-W.com and found the correct definition in less than five seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A canned message or email is one that has been pre-written in advance and is generic and not specific to any person. A company gets this question over and over, so they just send the same answer to everyone.

It’s a figure of speech that is sort of like making soup. You could buy a bunch of fancy ingredients, prepare them, and use a recipe to make unique soup; or you could just buy a can of soup and dump it out without putting in much effort. Although you can’t literally buy a “can of answers,” this is the same low-effort feeling you would get if you could.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!